# SMTPAppender for log4j -- can't get it to work

Tags: configuration, log4j, mule, smtpappender

I'm tying to add the SMTPAppender to an application for error notification (tomcat app).  I haven't been able to get it to work up to this point.  I have tried it using configuration both in the log4j.properties file as well as through the log4j.xml configuration.  I'm not seeing any errors in the log related to a misconfiguration of the appender setup.  I'm just not seeing any email attempts at all.  Initially I has to bring in javax.mail and javax.activation so I know that it's attempting to set up and use the SMTPAppender, but I'm not seeing anything as far as miconfiguration errors or emails that are sent when errors occur.

Here's the log4j.properties that I tried (changed the private info)

```
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=512
log4j.appender.email.To=myemail@mydomain.com
log4j.appender.email.From=from@mydomain.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=mysmtphost
log4j.appender.email.Subject=MULE -- error  
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=mysmtpuser
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=mysmtppassword
```

Here's the configuation that I tried in the log4j.xml file

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">      
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/apps/data/pbymuleservices.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1000KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p [%d{ISO8601}] (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender> 

<appender name="email" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="512" />
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="mysmtphost" />
    <param name="SMTPUsername" value="mysmtpusername" />
    <param name="SMTPPassword" value="mysmtppassword" />
    <param name="From" value="fromemail@mydomain.com" />
    <param name="To" value="toemail@mydomain.com" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="error" />
    <param name="Subject" value="MULE -- Error" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}]%n%n%-5p%n%n%c%n%n%m%n%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="error" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="com.mytoplevel.package" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/> 
    <appender-ref ref="file"/> 
</logger>

<logger name="org.mule" additivity="false">
    <level value="WARN"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/> 
    <appender-ref ref="file"/> 
</logger>

<logger name="com.mulesource" additivity="false">
    <level value="WARN"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/> 
    <appender-ref ref="file"/> 
</logger>               

<root>
    <priority value="error" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    <appender-ref ref="email"/> 
</root>
```

Anyone see anything that should keep this from working?  I'm not seeing any configuration related errors in the log, but I'm also not seeing emails when errors occur.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this param to the CATALINA_OPTS env variable: *-Dlog4j.debug* It will print where it's picking up the logging configuration from.